# Why Uniswap V3 factory saves parameters to storage and then deletes them instead of passing parameters to pool constructor directly

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, create2

In the [UniswapV3 contracts](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/05c10bf6d547d6121622ac51c457f93775e1df09/contracts/UniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol#L27) we can see that when creating a new pool, instead of passing parameters to the pool contract, we actually deploy the pool contract, and in the pool contract's constructor it reads from a storage variable in the pool factory.

`UniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol`:

```
function deploy(
    address factory,
    address token0,
    address token1,
    uint24 fee,
    int24 tickSpacing
) internal returns (address pool) {
    parameters = Parameters({factory: factory, token0: token0, token1: token1, fee: fee, tickSpacing: tickSpacing});
    pool = address(new UniswapV3Pool{salt: keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee))}());
    delete parameters; 
}
```

`UniswapV3Pool.sol`:

```
constructor() {
    int24 _tickSpacing;
    (factory, token0, token1, fee, _tickSpacing) = IUniswapV3PoolDeployer(msg.sender).parameters();
    tickSpacing = _tickSpacing;

    maxLiquidityPerTick = Tick.tickSpacingToMaxLiquidityPerTick(_tickSpacing);
}
```

Why doesn't the `UniswapV3Pool` contract take parameters? It feels like a waste of gas to read back to the original deployer contract for those variables.

For example, why not:

```
constructor(
    address _factory,
    address _token0,
    address _token1,
    uint24 _fee,
    int24 _tickSpacing
) {
    factory = _factory;
    token0 = _token0;
    token1 = _token1;
    fee = _fee;
    tickSpacing = _tickSpacing;
    maxLiquidityPerTick = Tick.tickSpacingToMaxLiquidityPerTick(_tickSpacing);
}
```

Comment: Some idea: Is there a governance control over any of these parameters?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The parameters are delete right after used, and they are created from the input parameters of another function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was made not for gas savings for sure, but for making pools addresses easily computable. They deploy pools with [CREATE2 opcode](https://www.evm.codes/#f5?fork=merge) and destination address is computed with the following formula:

> address = keccak256(0xff + sender_address + salt + keccak256(initialisation_code))[12:]

Unfortunately `initialisation_code` includes constructor arguments, so they did this trick to have no arguments and to have same `keccak256(initialisation_code)` for every pool. If they wouldn't do the trick, this kind of computation would require to have 20KB `initialisation_code` with concatenated ABI-encoded constructor arguments - literally impossible for arbitrary smart contract. Moreover address check is usually required in Uniswap v3 callback, see their [SwapRouter implementation details](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/6cce88e63e176af1ddb6cc56e029110289622317/contracts/libraries/CallbackValidation.sol#L33-L34).

This allows easily compute any pool address [by the salt depending on sorted tokens and pool fee](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/05c10bf6d547d6121622ac51c457f93775e1df09/contracts/UniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol#L35) in Solidity:

```
function getPoolAddress(address token0, address token1, uint24 fee) external view returns(address) {
    if (token0 > token1) {
        (token0, token1) = (token1, token0);
    }

    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee);

    return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(
            bytes1(0xff),
            factory_address,
            salt,
            initialisation_code_hash
        )
    ))));
}
```

Found their code here:

- TypeScript: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/test/shared/computePoolAddress.ts
- Solidity: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/PoolAddress.sol